# Can I use emacs with company-mode and company-go to complete Go's standard library function names?

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode, golang

Below is my emacs init file that relates to Go. I'm trying to use company mode to auto completes Go.

```
;;===================================================
; Golang related configuration
;;===================================================
(defun my-go-mode-hook ()
  ; Add go-guru
  (require 'go-guru)

  (require 'company)
  (require 'company-go)

  ; Use goimports instead of go-fmt
  (setq gofmt-command "goimports")
  ; Call Gofmt before saving
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save)
  ; Customize compile command to run go build
  (if (not (string-match "go" compile-command))
      (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
           ;"go build -v && go test -v && go vet"))
           "go run"))
  ; Godef jump key binding
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-.") 'godef-jump))
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook 'my-go-mode-hook)
; Highlight identifiers in Golang by default
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'go-guru-hl-identifier-mode)
```

However, it seems that the company mode can only completes words that have been used in the buffer. See below screen shot.

[image]

What I want is to complete Go's builtin functions, like `fmt.Fprintln`. It seems company mode can't do that. See below screen shot.

[image]

I want to confirm, is it true? Can emacs auto completes Go's builtin functions? Are there any example emacs init files that I can use as a reference? Thanks in advance.

---

## Update

Confirmed I installed gocode.

[image]

I've cleared my init.el and only contains the minimal code to do the completion, but it still not work (emacs restarted).

[image]

---

## Update2

Yes gocode is running.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell company-mode what backend to use. In my init file I have the following code

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends) '(company-go))
        (company-mode)))
```

You will also need the gocode autocomplete daemon which you can get by executing `go get github.com/nsf/gocode`.

Comment: hi Tephra, so all I need to do is add the code you pasted in order to get completion? Do I need to start gocode in a separate terminal? Does it work in terminal emacs, which is what I'm using.

Comment: Also do I need to press any key in order to trigger the completion? Or company will show it automatically?

Comment: When I type `fmt.` company-mode shows me all exposed methods that I can use without me having to press any key. You probably have to do a `go get github.com/nsf/gocode` also now that I come to think about it.

I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I already have gocode installed at my $GOPATH\bin. I tried your suggestion and only include the code you provided in my init file and it still not work. See my update image in my question.

Comment: You are using emacs GUI version or terminal version?

Comment: Is gocode running? I'm starting emacs in GUI mode but that shouldn't matter (as far as I know). What is the result of `ps aux | grep gocode`?

Comment: I checked, gocode is running. See my update2.

Comment: I think I found the reason. I guess it's because for some unknown reason gocode has been started and hung there. I checked gocode doc and found a command `gocode close` to properly shut down gocode. Then suddenly it works. Thank you very much for your help!