# Context-aware auto completion for Go

Tags: auto-complete-mode, golang

Is there any context-aware auto-completion for Go e.g 
if I enter "fmt." after importing the library, auto-completion should pop up and suggest me the functions like "Println" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I got here while searching for the same thing. I am trying [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) together with [auto-complete-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete).

I can't get it to complete on `.` though. Have to type one or two chars to get completion. Not sure if it is me or not possible. I am no emacs wizard..... yet.....

Answer (score 0):

There's a company-go backend available for the Go language in [company-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompanyMode) ([installation advice](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26822/8589), available elsewhere at Emacs Stack Exchange). It should be possible to activate any interactive function from company-mode, with a key-binding on the *Full Stop* character, "."

So far as in reviewing some existing reviews, it seems that company-mode is pretty widely adopted, for providing specialized code-completion functionality in Emacs. Guessing from some introductions, it may even provide a literal pop-up menu. Looking forward to seeing if the pop-up menu works out well with a local ncurses installation #HTH